# What is scattering of light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering

What actually we mean when we say scattering of light by a particle?
Is a **ray** of light on being by scattered by a particle  get divided into many sub rays that scattered in different direction ?

Or

A **Beam** of light when hit a particle , than the individual rays present in that beam get reflected in different directionsfroma that refer to scattering?
What does we mean when we say " infinite no. Of rays are coming from a single point from any objects " is that scattered single **ray** into "many" sub rays or individual rays from **beam** reflected on that point get scattered into different direction ?
[image]

(Look at circled part)
So does the incident light is "beam" or "ray" that get scattered? And help is to see an object?

Hope u got my idea!
Same with scattering of blue light in sky by gas molecules. Do they scatter beam or ray?

What actually is scattering!? Is a **ray** got divided into sub rays in many direction Or individualrays in a **beam**  got reflected in different direction from single point (thus helping in forming ingredients of it in our eyes and not showing reflection of our like mirror)?

One request please don't mark my question negative and don't close it , I know my questions are weird but I have no way to get my answers from anywhereIf u want any corrections just tell me I will try to make it. But don't close my question.

Comment: Scattering in general is the action of throwing some physical stuff to another objects and see what comes back on the other side (or at different angles).

Comment: Sir, can u tell pls that in diagram that incident ray,is a beam or ray of light? Because  when diffuse reflection take place they go in random direction FROM A  SINGLE POINT , so if it is a  ray how could one ray hitted on a point be reflected in many direction, there should be a particular angle of reflection accordingto surface of object, that's why I think that incident light (diagram) should be a beam .....so a beam has many rays a d different ray hit point but point has many irregularity so they scattered in many angles help us to see point from  any corner of room, am I correct? Pls tell

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of levels of abstraction that we can answer this on, but I'll keep this conversation classical as that's what seems appropriate.

Recall that when light hits a surface it can either be **reflected** or **absorbed**. In short, the term "scattering of light" just refers to the scenario when the light hits a surface and it is not **absorbed**.

When light is reflected, it always follows the law of reflection ($\theta_{in} = \theta_{out}$). This is what we call **specular reflection**. If light reflects off (i.e. scatters off) a flat surface like a mirror, then all of the rays pretty much go in the same direction. However, if this surface is jagged or bumpy then these rays will reflect in all different directions.

**Note**: The law of reflection is still being obeyed at all times, it's just that if you have a bumpy surface some of the light rays are hitting the side of the bump, some hit the top, some hit other bumps, etc.. This is what we call **diffuse** reflection.

Comment: Sir, can u tell pls that in diagram that incident ray,is a beam or ray of light? Because  when diffuse reflection take place they go in random direction FROM A  SINGLE POINT , so if it is a  ray how could one ray hitted on a point be reflected in many direction, there should be a particular angle of reflection accordingto surface of object, that's why I think that incident light (diagram) should be a beam .....so a beam has many rays a d different ray hit point but point has many irregularity so they scattered in many angles help us to see point from  any corner of room, am I correct? Pls tell